# Field userDAOService in com.restApi.java.jpa.UserDaoServiceCommandLineRunner required a bean of type 'service.UserDAOService' that could not be found

Tags: java, intellij-idea, compilation, runtime-error

I'm creating a simple persistance jpa based on a curse, but the code is not working and I can't find the problem.
This is the error:

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.

2019-09-06 14:21:19.692 ERROR 8280 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Field userDAOService in com.restApi.java.jpa.UserDaoServiceCommandLineRunner required a bean of type 'service.UserDAOService' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:

- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'service.UserDAOService' in your configuration.

Process finished with exit code 1

I'm using java openjdk 12 with springboot and Intellij idea. everything on windows 10.

**User.java**

```
package entity;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class User {
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String role;

    protected User(){

    }
    public User(String name, String role) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.role = role;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", role='" + role + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**UserDAOService.java**

```
package service;

import entity.User;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;

@Service
public class UserDAOService {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public long insert(User user){
        entityManager.persist(user);
        return user.getId();
    }
}
```

**UserDaoServiceCommandLineRunner.java**

```
package com.restApi.java.jpa;

import entity.User;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import service.UserDAOService;

@Component
public class UserDaoServiceCommandLineRunner implements CommandLineRunner 
{
    @Autowired
    private UserDAOService userDAOService;

    private static final Logger log = 
LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserDaoServiceCommandLineRunner.class);

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        User user = new User("Tom","Admin");
        long insert = userDAOService.insert(user);
        log.info("User Created"+ user);
    }
}
```

**JpaApplication.java**

```
package com.restApi.java.jpa;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class JpaApplication {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(JpaApplication.class, args);
   }

}
```

The code should show the message "User Created {user id}"

Sorry if the question and the info is not uploaded properly, this is my first question.

Best regards.

**UPDATE**
Thanks to user czpona comment the code now is running, but is still not showing the message.

The code for **JpaApplication.java** is now the following:
package com.restApi.java.jpa;

```
import entity.User;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import service.UserDAOService;

@SpringBootApplication
public class JpaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(JpaApplication.class, args);
    }
    public class UserDaoServiceCommandLineRunner implements 
CommandLineRunner {
        @Autowired
        private UserDAOService userDAOService;

        private final Logger log = 
LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserDaoServiceCommandLineRunner.class);

        @Override
        public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
            User user = new User("Toto","Admin");
            long insert = userDAOService.insert(user);
            log.info("User Created"+ user);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Exequiel, what is the purpose of UserDaoServiceCommandLineRunner? Why don't you put your code into JpaApplication directly?

Comment: Hi, I'm taking a course at Udemy, and the professor did it in this way. I haven't really tried to move the code to another class/file. I will try right now

Comment: Hi, now is running, but is not showing the message in the terminal.

Comment: have a look at https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-console-app. It shows how CommandLineRunner interface was meant to be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two problems with your code

First is your project structure

All classes you scan ( entities, components, services ..) must be located in the same package ( or in sub-packages ) your main class `JpaApplication` located in, to make the Spring boot app able to scan them.

So, class `User` should be under `com.restApi.java.jpa.entity` package instead of `entity`

and `UserDAOService` should be under `com.restApi.java.jpa.service` package instead of `service`

just like :

```
package com.restApi.java.jpa.entity;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
@Entity
public class User {
     *
     *
    }
```

and UserDAOService class like:

```
package com.restApi.java.jpa.service;

import com.restApi.java.jpa.entity.User;
*
import javax.transaction.Transactional;

@Service
public class UserDAOService {
       *
       *
```

Another thing,

In order to make the `entityManager.persist(user)` works, you have to open a transaction, so you can annotate your method with `@Transational`, like:

```
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
*
@Transactional
public long insert(User user){
        entityManager.persist(user);
        return user.getId();
    }
```

Comment: Yes! that was the problem, the structure was wrong. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

In your JpaApplication you should mention the packages to be scanned for beans

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"service"})
```

But you are not executing your CommandLineRunner. Is it what you want to do?